# How to take this limit

Tags: limits

How do I take limits of the form $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left((x - 1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\right)$$?

Using boundedness of $\sin$ seems wrong.

Comment: Use boundedness of sin.

Comment: If you have a reason something "seems wrong" then that usually points you to a disproof. However if you don't have a reason then you might want to check the details, because it might actually work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly
$$- (x - 1) \leq (x - 1)\sin \left( {\frac{x}{{x - 1}}} \right) \leq (x - 1)$$
and
$\pm(x - 1) \to 0$ as $x \to 1$, so by the squeeze theorem we know that
$$(x - 1)\sin \left( {\frac{x}{{x - 1}}} \right) \to 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

Why does using boundedness seem wrong?

We have for all $x \in \mathbb R$ that
\[
  0 \le \left|(x-1)\sin\frac x{x-1}\right| \le \left|x-1\right| 
\]
As $\lim_{x\to 1} 0 = \lim_{x\to 1} \left|x-1\right| = 0$, we have
\[
\lim_{x\to 1} (x-1)\sin\frac x{x-1} = 0
\]
by the sandwich theorem.